# Смена свойств CSS при клике на текст

Tags: javascript, css

```
$("#NewPost").live("focus", function(){
        $(this).animate({height:112},300);
    }).bind("keydown", function(e) {
            e = e || window.event;
            if (e.keyCode === 13 && e.ctrlKey) {sendPostY();}
        });

$(function(){
    $(document).click(function(event) {
        if ($(event.target).closest("#NewPost").length) return;
        $("#NewPost").animate({height:26},300);
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Надо сделать так, что бы если в контейнере #NewPost есть текст, то при клике на документ блок не изменяет свойства CSS по высоте. Если же текста нету, то при клике на документ - блок сворачивается.

Comment: @Bagner, стандартный комментарий: на странице не может быть больше одного элемента с одним айдишником. Все скрипты, которые предполагают обратное, работать не будут.

Answer (score 2):

Может так?

```
$(document).click(function() {
    if ($("#NewPost").text().length)
        $("#NewPost").animate({height:26},300);
});
```